# how to check the spark ui for a recent application run

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have the following script which i am running for testing on the master node of emr

I have file called `spark_test.py` as below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()

print("Spark Version:",spark.version)

sc = spark.sparkContext

print('Master :',sc.master)

print('Default Parallelism :',sc.defaultParallelism)

print('AQE Enabled :',spark.conf.get('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled'))

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled','true')

print('AQE Enabled :',spark.conf.get('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled'))

df = spark.read.load("/home/hadoop/sample.csv",format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="true", header="true")

print('No of partitions in the dataframe :',df.rdd.getNumPartitions())

print(sc.uiWebUrl)

spark.stop()

print("Spark Version:",spark.version)

print('Master :',sc.master)
```

run it as

```
(venv) [hadoop@xxx]$ python spark_test.py 
24/02/16 09:20:41 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark Version: 2.4.3
Master : local[*]
Default Parallelism : 4
AQE Enabled : false
AQE Enabled : true
No of partitions in the dataframe : 8                                           
http://ip-xx.xx.xx.xx.ec2.internal:4040
Spark Version: 2.4.3
Master : local[*]
```

I want to check the spark ui for this script.

I tried to access, `http://ip-xx.xx.xx.xx.ec2.internal:4040`  but it says `site cant be reached`

(note: i am access the UI using ssh tunneling on my local)

Where i can access the spark history server mentioned in the emr applications, but there i dont see any details of this, may be because i ran it standalone using master "local[*]" instead of yarn

[image]

how to access the spark ui for any standalone scripts

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can try to implement

- Authorize your local IP address permission to access the Primary node's DNS address [Follow these steps to authorize your local IP and allow inbound SSH connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-ssh-prereqs.html)
- Enable local port forwarding so that you can access the Spark History UI from the local address + port you configure. [Steps here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel-local.html#ssh-tunnel-local-linux)

The command from the documentation is as follows:

```bash
ssh -i ~/mykeypair.pem -N -L 8157:ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8088 hadoop@ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

> In this example command accesses the ResourceManager web interface by forwarding traffic on local port `8157` (a randomly chosen unused local port) to port 8088 on the master node's local web server. In the command, replace `~/mykeypair.pem` with the location and file name of your `.pem` file and replace `ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com` with the master public DNS name of your cluster. To access a different web interface, replace `8088` with the appropriate port number. For example, replace `8088` with `8890` for the Zeppelin interface.

And, please note that you can only access the Spark UI (on the local cluster/remote cluster) only when the Spark session is active. Once you invoke `spark.stop()` it will stop the Spark Web UI from being active.

Hence, run a simple user input command such as `input(Press any key to continue..)` before you invoke `spark.stop()`. That way, the UI will be active till you come back to the terminal and perform a key press and disable it.